# How to handle events in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, event-handling

I am going to implement a feature , where my application has to receive events of a camera from ( Event push server).

This server will push the events and my application has to receive and show in the notification bar.

e.g like the Facebook app or WhatsApp app, where in we receive the new message on the notification bar, even though the app is not in active state.

So to implement it:

1. What all pre requisetes i need. e.g information about the Event server?
2. Information on what protocol used in the server?
3. what is required on the Android side to implement this feature.

Please tell me how to proceed to implement on Android application side.

Answer (score 0):

The programs like facebook using [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to take events in background. Use [JSON](http://json.org/) files for data interchange. Im using [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to keep in touch with my activity. BroadcastReceiver its a very nice tool to communicate your service with activity.

```
Intent in = new Intent("SOMEACTION");
sendBroadcast(in);
```

Sending intent to you activity after handling response.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();

  // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
      new IntentFilter("my-event"));
}

// handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Extract data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
  }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
  // Unregister since the activity is not visible
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: If i understand your answer. It says..: First- I need to have a service which runs in background to check for the messages coming from the Event Push server...Second - I should use JSON for receiving data from the server and handling the data inside my application... Third - After receiving the data, i should show it on the notification bar.... But i did not understand the Broadcast receiver part. Why and where to use in my scenario.

Comment: Yes, that's right ! Broadcast its just callback system to communicate with parts of your program.